# JavaScript checking & adding text to a table dynamically on submit button click

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createtextnode

Basically my HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="post" name="htmlform" onsubmit = "checkFields()">
  <table style="width: 479px;" border="30" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top"><span id="firstNameSpan" >First Name *</span></td>
  <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                    size="30" maxlength="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top"><span id = "lastNameSpan" >Last Name *</span></td>
  <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="last_name" size="30" maxlength="50"/> 
      /td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="sex" 
  value="male" /> Male <input type="radio" name="sex" 
  value="female" /> Female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" 
       /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
```

When the form is submitted, the onsubmit() event checks if first_name textfield is blank, if it is then the label or span to its left is appended to output "first name*" + " you must enter a first name" and similarly for last name and sex.

The problem is that the text in the table does not update with appendchild.  When I enclosed the statement in an alert for debugging the message is appended then disappears.

The JavaScript code is below for the onsubmit = "checkFields()".

```
function checkFields() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    if (firstName == "") {
        //<span style='color:red'> Please enter a first name </span>
        var nameHint = " Please enter a first name";
        var node = document.getElementById("firstNameSpan");
        //alert(node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint)) );
        //not working
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));

    } if (lastName == "") {
        //additional code
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated.  Also are there any JavaScript debuggers?

Regards

David D

Comment: In `additional code` are you returning `false` from the function? You would need to do so if you want to halt form submission.  And remove the whitespace around `=` in `onsubmit = `

Comment: Your browser has a built-in JS debugger.  Chrome/Safari have developer tools in the menus. Firefox has a console, plus the Firebug extension, F12 in IE to open developer tools.

Comment: If you haven't already considered it and the requirements allow it, you should look into jQuery to do client side work.  There is even a validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Ive edited it to remove the else statement as I want all 3 left-side texts to change on an event reacting to an empty or unselected field. I use firefox Michael so I will look into Firebug

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sample code is not working due to incorrect html. `document.getElementById("last_name")` will return undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/5E6my/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, Im getting the ropes of JFiddle the split screen is very useful although the error messages are not useful for debugging.  Here is the completed code (1) HTML (2) JavaScript.

```
<form method="post" name="htmlform" onsubmit="return checkFields();">
  <table style="width: 479px;" border="30" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top"><span id="firstNameSpan" >First Name *</span></td>
  <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                                            size="30" maxlength="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top"><span id = "lastNameSpan" >Last Name *</span></td>
  <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" size="30" 
  maxlength="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2" id = "sexMessage">
      Please select Male or Female*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><input type="radio"
   name="sex" value="male" /> Male <input type="radio" name="sex"
  value="female" /> Female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"    
   /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
```

The JavaScript code to react to the onsubmit button's unfilled fields in the form are:  (any ways to make this code simpler??)

```
window.checkFields = function()
  {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name");
  var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name");
  if(firstName.value == "")
  {
  //<span style='color:red'> Please enter a first name </span>
    var nameHint = " *Please enter a first name ";
    var fnNode = document.getElementById("firstNameSpan");
    while(fnNode.firstChild)
    {
        fnNode.removeChild(fnNode.firstChild)
    }
    fnNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
    fnNode.style.color="red";

  } else{
      var nameHint = " First Name *";
      var fnNode = document.getElementById("firstNameSpan");
      while(fnNode.firstChild)
      {
        fnNode.removeChild(fnNode.firstChild)
      }
      fnNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
      fnNode.style.color="black";
  }
  if (lastName.value == "")
  {
  //additional code
    var nameHint = " *Please enter a last name";
    var lnNode = document.getElementById("lastNameSpan");
    while(lnNode.firstChild)
    {
        lnNode.removeChild(lnNode.firstChild)
    }
    lnNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
    lnNode.style.color="red";
  } else{
      var nameHint = " Last Name *";
      var lnNode = document.getElementById("lastNameSpan");
      while(lnNode.firstChild)
      {
        lnNode.removeChild(lnNode.firstChild)
      }
      lnNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
      lnNode.style.color="black";
  }
      var radios = document.getElementsByName("sex");
      var radioValue = ""
      for(var i=0; i<radios.length; i++)
      {
          if(radios[i].checked)
          {
              radioValue = radios[i].value;
          }

      }
      if(radioValue === "")
      {
          var sexNode = document.getElementById("sexMessage");
          var nameHint = "*You did not choose a sex";
          while(sexNode.firstChild)
          {
              sexNode.removeChild(sexNode.firstChild);
          }
          sexNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
          sexNode.style.color="red";
      } else {
          var sexNode = document.getElementById("sexMessage");
          var nameHint = "Please select Male or Female*";
          while(sexNode.firstChild)
          {
              sexNode.removeChild(sexNode.firstChild);
          }
          sexNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameHint));
          sexNode.style.color="black";
      }               
      return false;
  }
```

The trick is to use as Yury suggested was the onsubmit="return checkfields()" and then in the code block to use window.checkFields = function() { etc.

One question that I have... is JQuery a lot simpler to use, im learning JavaScript before JQuery... should I skip to JQUery instead.  Also does JQuery support the AJAX framework?

Much appreciated

David